# SQL Server Unit Test Project template missing

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I am looking to implement Unit Testing of a database project I have created following this tutorial

[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2012/12/07/getting-started-with-sql-server-database-unit-testing-in-ssdt.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+ssdtblog+(SQL+Server+Developer+Tools+Team+Blog)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2012/12/07/getting-started-with-sql-server-database-unit-testing-in-ssdt.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+ssdtblog+%28SQL+Server+Developer+Tools+Team+Blog%29)

I have Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate Installed, and the latest update for SSDT, but I do not have the SQL Server Test Project Template available in Visual Studio. If I go to Templates, than Visual C#, the SQL Server folder only contains SQL Server Database Project. What do I need to do to configure the SQL Server Test Project?

Answer (score 3):

Database unit tests in VS2012 and VS2013 just use the standard unit test project, like so:

1. Right-click on your solution and choose Add > New Project...
2. In the Add New Project dialog, select Visual C# > Test > Unit Test Project, enter a name and click OK.
3. In Solution Explorer, right click on the new unit test project and choose Add > New Item...
4. In the Add New Item dialog, select SQL Server > SQL Server Unit Test.

It's also possible to right-click on a stored procedure, etc. in SQL Server Object Explorer and choose Create Unit Test.

Comment: It is little confusing in VS12 there is no database unit testing. It is sql server unit testing. But in VS10 there is database unit testing and sql server unit testing. So when I was in vs10 and created sql server unit testing thinking it is same as vs12 I was wrong. vs12 sql server unit testing is equivalent of vs10 database unit testing.

Comment: I don't have CreateUnit Test on my Visual Studio 2015 Professional version, but I can use add SQL Server Unit Test